# A direct proportionality problem: alternative proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof, education

The price of artisanal ice cream is $60\%$ labor cost and $40\%$ ingredient cost. Production costs then experience increases: $32\%$ for labor, $52\%$ for ingredients. Write the law that expresses the price a of ice cream after the increases as a function of the price $b$ of ice cream before the increases and determine what kind of proportionality exists between $a$ and $b$.
What is the total percentage increase in the price of ice cream?

**My attempts**:
Let us call $p_1$
the initial price. It we know to be composed of $p_1=0.6x+0.4y$ where $x$ is the cost of manpower  and $y$  is the cost of ingredients. Assuming $x=y=1$ we have $p_1=1$. Calling $p_2$
the price after increases, we can say that $$p_2=1.32\cdot 0.6x+1.52\cdot 0.4y=0.792x+0.608y$$ By posing again in this case $x=y=1$ we have that $p_2=1.4$. Thus $p_2=1.4\cdot 1 p_1$ that is, a direct proportionality. Trivially, the total percentage increase in the price of ice cream therefore turns out to be $40\%=0.4$.

> Is there an alternative proof with the complete steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your $x$ and $y$. The cost of Labour is $x = 0.6p_1$ and the cost of ingredients is $y = 0.4p_1$.

You should have
$$
p_1 = \underbrace{0.4 p_1}_{\text{labour}} + \underbrace{0.6 p_1}_{\text{ingerdients}}
$$
Then,
$$
p_2 = (1.52)(0.4 p_1) + (1.32)(0.6p_1) = 1.4 p_1.
$$

Comment: I agree with Quoka. Sebastiano's work is confusing. In high school, this kind of variation is called partial variation. That is, the price is the sum of 2 parts, labour and ingradients. Each part has variation of its own.

Comment: @LiKwokKeung I am agree totally with you.